# Getting 4 rows instead of 2 in a simple inner join in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a new learner to the sql language. My instructor gave me a task to comprehend the output of an inner join of two tables containing only one column named id and the number 1 inserted in both the tables twice.

The tables are named T1 and T2 and are visible in the db as shown below.

**T1**       \    **T2**

```
|ID |    | ID |
|---|    |----|
|1  |    |  1 |
|1  |    |  1 |
```

when i perform an inner join on these tables with the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

I am getting the query result as:

```
|ID | ID_1 |
|---|------|  
|1  |  1   |
|1  |  1   |
|1  |  1   |
|1  |  1   |
```

From my understanding the inner join retrieves distinct, non duplicate rows from both the tables, and should have just 2 rows in the output. why am i getting 4 rows? Please help me understand.

My apologies if this question is too basic and not upto the site's standards.

Comment: Please can you try to explain your tables again ? You can not have two columns with same name...

Comment: My apologies, i did not mean to represent the two columns belonging to the same table, there is one id column in T1 and one id column in T2. i couldn't figure out how to mark the table names as such in the question,

Comment: I have made changes reflecting the tables seperately now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From my understanding the inner join retrieves distinct, non duplicate rows from both the tables

Simple.  Your understanding is wrong.

`JOIN` has no relationship to "distinct" or "non-duplicate" rows.  It simply produces *all* combinations of rows from the two tables that match the `ON` conditions (plus additional rows for an outer join).

Perhaps you are confusing `JOIN` with `UNION` -- which *does* remove duplicates.  That said, I strongly recommend `UNION ALL` in most circumstances, because that does not incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So in essence because both tables have only one value repeated twice, i am seeing a combination join output of 2*2 = 4 rows? The first row from T1 is being parsed with the two rows of T2 and then the same is being done with the second row of T1. So 4 rows total. Is this correct?

Comment: @ncircler . . . Exactly.  Each row in each table is being matched with all rows in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you need:

```
select distinct T.rn, T.id, T2.id
from (select distinct ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.id) rn, T1.id from T1) T
join T2 on T.id = T2.id
order by T.rn;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Yes using a new variable rn and distinct within a nested subquery produces the output of 2 rows as i initially perceived. But my task was to comprehend why it produced 4 rows. I believe Gordon explained the join better as an operation combining rows from 2 tables. Really appreciate the valuable insight on the code.

Comment: You are welcome. I did not understand you need the explanation , I thought you ned the solution that results with two rows :) Cheers